# react-flow renderer edges remain in ui without any parents

Tags: reactjs

I implement a web page in reactjs, and should show some input and output nodes and the edges between them. the data inside each nodes will change periodically and i need to change the data for them time to time.
i implemented it and works fine, but after stay in this page for a minute it can not remove the previous edges and it remain in the web page.

I uploaded a video clip about this issue
any idea about this issue?

[issue with edges in react flow- youtube link](https://youtu.be/K735G1F5cQc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue, i set the random generated id for edges, which sometimes make a repeated id and cause this issue, when i set the unique id for each edges issue solved. :)